# How to get notified by the Linux kernel if a new interface has been attached?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver

I want to be able to detect when a new external device is connected to the linux system and upon that send a notification message to a running process.

I was wondering if there is any other solution than periodically scan for /dev/
and detect if anything has changed.

Comment: use [udev](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/udev/udev.html)

Comment: May as well have Brian put his response as an answer to earn the checkmark

Answer (score 3):

While you can use *udev*, the underlying mechanism is [*netlink*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html).  Interfaces themselves are not normally in `/dev`, but do show up under `/sys/class/net` as sub-directories.  However, the [hotplug.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/pending/hotplug.txt) gives a good start to inspecting kernel events.  Run the sample code and examine the *netlink* data when an interface is connected.  The text is ASCII that any *user space* application can parse and use.